# Using $sum and $avg with $addFields in MongoDB Aggregation

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

According to the docs, both `$avg` and `$sum` are available in the `$project` and `$group` stages only.

So my question is, when it comes to `$addFields`, can I do this as a stage in my aggregation pipeline?:

```
// stage 5
$addFields: {
  "companyTransactionAvg": {
    "$avg": {
      "$sum": "$totals.sixWeekTransactionAvg"
    }
  }
}
```

This doesn't error out. I get a numerical value as a result. Is this doing what I think it is, or is something else happening? I'm trying to get the average of all `sixWeekTransactionAvg` values across all documents.

Will this work as an independent stage in my pipeline, or does this need to explicitly be included in either a `$project` or `$group` stage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize now that while one can do this, all that's really happening here is that one is getting the average of a sum of one value. Because there's no $grouping going on, just one document, not all, is being read, and the average (`$avg`) of the `$sum` of that value from that one document is being outputted. And of course, considering it's only one value, the `$avg` of the `$sum` is always going to be the same as the original value itself.

```
value: 10
averageOfValue: 10
```